# Consume REST API using java - SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, security, ssl, https

I am trying to consume a REST API using Java. however, when I run the code it shows me this exception.
I didn't understand what does it mean, I try to search for the solution but I can't get it :(

this is the connection code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.authentication.HttpAuthenticationFeature;

public class connectToAPI {
         public static void main(String[] args) {

try{
URL url = new URL("https://ip:port/rest/path");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
String userpassword = "user:pass";
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic "+
              userpassword);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.flush();
int status = 0;
if( null != conn ){
status = conn.getResponseCode();
}

if( status != 0){
       System.out.println("status!=0");
if( status == 200 ){

       System.out.println("status==200");
//SUCCESS message
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));



}else if(status == 401){

       System.out.println("status==401");



}else if(status == 501){

       System.out.println("status==501");



}else if( status == 503){

       System.out.println("status==503");



}





}



} catch (Exception e) {

e.printStackTrace();

}

}
              }
```

when I run the code it shows me this exception:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address ip found
>
> ```
>    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
>
>    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
>
>    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
>
>    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
>
>    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
>
>    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
>
>    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
>
>    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
>
>    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
>
>    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
>
>    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
>
>    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
>
>    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
>
>    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
>
>    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
>
>    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
>
>    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
>
>    at alert.connectToBAM.main(connectToBAM.java:77)
> ```
>
> Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject
>   alternative names matching IP address ip found
>
> ```
>    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(Unknown Source)
>
>    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(Unknown Source)
>
>    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(Unknown Source)
>
>    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(Unknown Source)
>
>    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
>
>    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
>
>    ... 14 more
> ```

I also tried jersey clinet:

```
javax.ws.rs.client.Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

                           WebTarget target = client.target("https://ip:port/rest/path");

                           System.out.println(

                                         target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class));
```

it shows this error:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names
>   matching IP address ip found
>
> ```
>    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:284)
>
>    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:278)
>
>    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$1(JerseyInvocation.java:767)
>
>    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
>
>    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
>
>    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:229)
>
>    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:414)
>
>    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:765)
>
>    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:428)
>
>    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:324)
>
>    at alert.connectToBAM.main(connectToBAM.java:47)
> ```

Any idea? pleaseeee, it is my graduation project :(

Comment: What is the exact URL you're attempting to hit?

In both cases I'm seeing that you attempt to connect to:

"https://ip:port/rest/path" 

Are you sure you're using the correct address?

Answer (score 0):

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException
```

Generally these type of exceptions are occurs due to certificate verification issue of the certificate, follow the below steps :
1. Download the certificate from the browser and add it to `cacerts` file in the jre folder
2. we need to add some java code to verify the certificate using TrustManager.
Code is given below :

```
public static void trustManager()
{
    try 
    {

        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]
                {
                        new X509TrustManager()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                                    throws CertificateException {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                                    throws CertificateException {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            }
                            @Override
                            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                return null;
                            }

                        }
                };

        //Create an Instance for SSLContext class
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

        //overload init method 
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());

        //Use static method setDefaultSSLSocketFactory
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

        //Create Instance for Hostname verifier and override verify() method
        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {

            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) 
            {
                return true;
            }

        };

        //Verify hostname using static method setDefaultHostnameVerifier
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Whenever you are trying to execute just call this method at first in main method. Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Where can I find the cecerts file? + Where should I add this code? And when should I call it :(?

Comment: `JAVA_HOME---> JRE -->lib---> security--> cacerts.`  This is the path to find cacerts file. At first download the certificate from the browser and add the certificate into cacerts file using portecle (watch the video in youtube how to add certificate using portecle). After adding certificate to cacerts file, create a method (in my case i created `trustManager()` method) in your program and insert the provided code in that method. and call that method in main method. Remember you have to give first priority to call this method in main method.